# Why NEXTAUTH_URL in .env file ignored after firebase deploy?

Tags: firebase, next.js, environment-variables, next-auth

I use next-auth to made a session, and deploy with firebase.
In local, I confirmed next-auth basepath changed,.
But after deploy, next-auth basepath don't changed.
The basepath is always "https://localhost:3000"
I think the firebase don't recognized the .env file.
I made the .env file in /root and /root/functions.
How can I fix the error?

It's my .env file

```js
NEXTAUTH_URL="my deployed url"
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is the only env variable you have, you can set it in the command line or in your package.json script:

```
"scripts: {
  ...
  "deploy": NEXTAUTH_URL=my_deployed_url firebase deploy ......,
  ...
}
```

if you have multiple env variables inside your env file, check if this file is been copied to your build folder after nextjs has finished the build + export process.

one more hint: in nextJS all env variables those should be visible/shared with your browser should start with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` so your variable will be `NEXT_PUBLIC_NEXTAUTH_URL`

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If your firebase is also using Google Cloud Platform, you should be setting your environment variables there and not in a .env file. Docs: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/environment-variables